# HighCharts Hide Series Name from the Legend

Tags: javascript, hide, highcharts, legend, series

I try to solve this problem several times and give up. Now, when I have met him again, I decided to ask for some help.

I have this code for my Legend:

```
legend:
{
    layout: 'vertical',
    align: 'right',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    x: -10,
    y: 100,
    borderWidth: 0,
    
    
    
    labelFormatter: function() 
    {
        if(this.name!='Series 1')
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        else
        {
            return 'Legend';
        }
    }
}
```

If I change the return from 'Legend' to '' the text is not shown but still there is a 'dash' on the top of the legend. If I do not use label formater function  I have 'Series 1' + 'dash' like a first row in my legend. How to hide them?

Please, note my version is : Highcharts-2.0.5

This is a simple view of my legend and the dash I want to remove:

[image: Sample Image]

Answer (score 241, accepted):

If you don't want to show the series names in the legend you can disable them by setting `showInLegend:false`.

example:

```
series: [{
   showInLegend: false,             
   name: "<b><?php echo $title; ?></b>",
   data: [<?php echo $yaxis; ?>],
}]
```

You get other options here.

- [legend options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend)
- [other chart options](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts)

Comment: using "showInLegend: false" really fixed my problem. I wonder if this options only hides the series name, because the legend is still displaying the data (as I want).

Comment: Assuming if these options are enabled then it'll give a clear view, so they're enabled by default. if don't need them remove it. that's what you've done here.

Answer (score 23):

Set showInLegend to false.

```
series: [{
            showInLegend: false,
            name: 'Series',
            data: value                
        }]
```

Answer (score 8):

`showInLegend` is a **series-specific option** that can hide the series from the legend. If the requirement is to hide the legends completely then it is better to use `enabled: false` property as shown below:

`legend: {
    enabled: false
 }`

More information about `legend` is [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend)

Answer (score 6):

Looks like HighChart 2.2.0 has resolved this issue. I tried it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mvPFG/) with the same code you have, and the first series is hidden now. Could you try it with HighChart 2.2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Replace return 'Legend' by return ''