# DotNetHighcharts - Hide specific legend label

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, highcharts, dotnethighcharts

Having a lot of trouble hiding one particular Series label from the overall legend using DotNetHighcharts.

I have seen this done for highcharts.js in the following questions accepted answer

[HighCharts Hide Series Name from the Legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9479370/highcharts-hide-series-name-from-the-legend)

However I can't find any way to do it in C#. The reason is because I have a transparent series (bar) on my graph which I need the data from and this feature will solve my issue.

The only thing I've seen close in DotNetHighcharts is plotOptions showInLegend which hides the legend for everything.

The lack of documentation for DotNetHighcharts is pretty aggravating.

Answer (score 1):

The `showInLegend` attribute can be used at the series level as well as at the `plotOptions` level.

[This Highcharts demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-showinlegend/) shows how this is done:

```
    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        showInLegend: false
    }]
```

Please let me know how well this translates to the DotNetHighcharts world.